# (Java Spigot) Как можно узнать какие права нужны для использования команд?

Tags: java, permissions, minecraft

Пишу серверный плагин для minecraft (дополнительные права на сервере(vip, admin и т.п. помимо op)), используя spigot. Столкнулся с проблемой. По идеи PlayerComandPreprocessEvent передаёт только игрока, название команды, которая была вбита и ещё по мелочи. Мне же нужно узнать какие права нужны, чтобы использовать эту команду, но к сожалению я не могу получить из event.GetPermission(), так как это просто не предусмотрено. Очень не хотелось для отдельной команды прописывать проверку прав, так там их больше нескольких тысяч, а ещё есть команды из плагинов. По идеи это передаёт Command, но я не знаю как её получить или как преобразовать event в Command. Помогите пожалуйста, уже 2-ой день бьюсь, на форумах приводят пример с отдельными командами, название которых они уже знают.

```
@EventHandler
public void onCmd(PlayerCommandPreprocessEvent event){
    Player player = event.getPlayer();
    if(player.hasPermission(event.GetPermission())) // event.GetPermission() просто не существует
    {
        // делаем команду
    }
    else
    {
        // не делаем команду   
        // выкидываем собственную ошибку в чат, что у игрока нет прав. Не даём выкинуть в чат стандартную ошибку.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разобрался в теме, spigot сам проверяет привилегии игрока, так что совершенно не надо это проверять через код. Это работает как на консольные команды, так и на любые другие ивенты. Это нужно делать, только если есть специфичная команда, при которой что-то должно произойти.